How are object class definitions imported?
It's not clear to me what exactly is going on as I import a class definition.   As shown in the following code snippet,  I started out without a class called "Wave" in my environment.  Then I create the object wave , after which the defined class "Wave" is available in my console environment.
But wave is not an object of class "Wave" .  What is it?
Functions such as findClass() don't find the "Wave" class.  Where is it "hiding"?
What exactly is wave , as it's not a defined class?
edit
equally important: how is it that merely typing tuneR::Wave makes the class constructor available to my working environment?
# verify "Wave" class doesn't exist
>> foo <- new("Wave")
Error in getClass(Class, where = topenv(parent.frame())) : 
  “Wave” is not a defined class
# this doesn't work
>> foo <- new("tunerR::Wave")
Error in getClass(Class, where = topenv(parent.frame())) : 
  “tunerR::Wave” is not a defined class

# this does work
    >> wave <- tuneR::Wave
    >>wave
   standardGeneric for "Wave" defined from package "tuneR"
function (left, ...) 
standardGeneric("Wave")
<bytecode: 0x7fbdc6c84020>
<environment: 0x7fbdc6c638a8>
Methods may be defined for arguments: left
Use  showMethods(Wave)  for currently available ones.

>>foo <- new("Wave")
 class(foo)
[1] "Wave"
attr(,"package")
[1] "tuneR"

>>bar <- new('wave')
Error in getClass(Class, where = topenv(parent.frame())) : 
  “wave” is not a defined class


I don't know the tuneR package, but it looks like tuneR::Wave is a constructor for a "Wave" object.  So wave is another copy of the same constructor.  I'm not sure it's a constructor, printing it just showed it to be a generic function.  But the wave object is not a class, it's a function.
There's also a class named "Wave" in tuneR, and S4 classes are objects, but I don't think that object is the class.

That makes sense so far as my wondering what my wave object is.   But,  how does tuneR::Wave as a command load or connect the definition of the Wave class into my workspace?

Calling tuneR::<anything> causes the tuneR package to load.  That loads class definitions from that package into the R environment.  I think the "R Internals" document should describe what happens in lots of detail, but if not, you may have to look at the methods package source code.
